# Programming Linux serial timings

Tags: c++, linux

im currently trying to write a small program that gets values through the serial port, and presents it on the screen. Ive read several guides for this, mostly this [Link](http://mirror.datenwolf.net/serial/).

Now i got in some trouble with what i believe is the timing, so i wrote two small pieces of code to see if i could narrow the problem down.

The code posted here is one sender and one reciever, the sender just outputs 11:22 and the receiever should recieve this and present on the screen. Now it sort of does this, but i get lots of blank lines, and some skipped letters.
I guess im probably missing something fundamental, due to lack of knowledge :)

Please see the code below:
Note, this is very crude & the indention got screwed up men trying to copy and paste from gvim.. :)

Receiver:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;
int main()
{

int fd;          //desc for serial port.

char in[20];    //Char array for data from serial port



struct termios options;


tcgetattr(fd,&options);

cfsetispeed(&options,B19200);
cfsetospeed(&options,B19200);

options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);


options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
//options.c_cc[VMIN] = 5;


tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&options);

fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);



if (fd == -1)
{
    cout << "Could not open port." << endl;
}
else
fcntl(fd,F_SETFL,0);



while(1){





read (fd, in,sizeof in);


cout << in << endl;



}








}
```

Sender:
        (Same includes as the above)

```
    int main()
     {

    int fd;
    struct termios options;


    tcgetattr(fd, &options);
    cfsetispeed(&options, B19200);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B19200);

    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    options.c_oflag |=OPOST;

    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW, &options);

    fd = open("/dev/ttyS0",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if (fd == -1)   
    {
    cout << "Cannot open port" << endl;
    }                       
    else                            
    fcntl(fd,F_SETFL,0);                    





  while(1){                                                              

    write(fd,"11:22\n",6);                                                                  
    usleep(1000); //Have a little break between the messages.. Prob not neceserry.
    }
```

}

Comment: It appears that both Receiver and Sender are the same code.

Comment: BTW, you're doing `tcsetattr(fd,...)` et. al. before the `fd = open(...`. (i.e.) they're operating on an `fd` value that is undefined

Comment: Hey Craig, thank you for your input! actually i forgot to mention this, i was unsure of what way around it should be, naturally it would be as you stated, but in my frustration i changed it. The interesting thing though, is that the settings work both way around. Ive tried to change the baudrate to confirm this. So i have no idea why that works though. Maybe it does update this after the "fcntl", so its just dumb luck?

Comment: After some more experimenting, it seems like there is characters left on the buffer,Are they there until next transmission? I noticed that when i pull the plug, it just repeats the last digits, this is probably why i get "cutoffs" and so..